# Impute based on condition in mice

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I am using `mice` for imputation and want to impute data in a column based on the condition of another column. Consider the following data:

```r
d <- data.frame(X1 = c(0, 1, 2, 3),
                X2 = c(NA, 5, NA, 7))

  X1 X2
1  0 NA
2  1  5
3  2 NA
4  3  7
```

I want to impute missing values in `X2` where `X1 > 0`

```r
  X1 X2
1  0 NA <-- do not impute
2  1  5
3  2 NA <-- impute
4  3  7
```

Comment: What method? What values do you want to impute

Comment: @KU99 I will probably use `2l.pmm`. In this example, I want to impute missingness in `X2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `where` argument in the `mice` function. It should be a logical matrix of same dimensions as your data frame and by default it is `TRUE` for every value that is `NA` in the data frame. In your case, you want to make some changes to that matrix.

Given, that missings in any other variable that you did not mention should be imputed without conditions, you can use this:

```
d.where <- is.na(d)
d.where[d$X1 <= 0, names(d)=="X2"] <- FALSE
```

And then use this matrix in your call to `mice::mice(...)`:

```
d.mids <- mice(data=d, where=d.where)
```

Comment: This looks great, except that when I run where this code I get the following errors:
`In stats::runif(N, 0, fg1/noise) : NAs produced`

`In imputes[cc] <- do.call(f, args = args) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`